# Use function as param

Tags: php, slim, callable

I have a class

```
class Contact {       
public function searchByPhone(ServerRequestInterface $request, BaseResponse $response, $args) {
    return 'somedata';
  }
}
```

Slim framework uses this method

```
$app->get("/searchByPhone/2342", Contact::class . ':searchByPhone');
```

I want use

```
$app->get("/searchByPhone/2342", Contact::searchByPhone());
```

So that when I click on a function NetBeans will take me to the right place in the code.
How do I do this?

Comment: This is not a good idea. You should not change your code to adjust how your IDE behaves. Try other options like [PHPDoc comments](https://manual.phpdoc.org/HTMLSmartyConverter/HandS/phpDocumentor/tutorial_tags.see.pkg.html) which might come in handy in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use a Single Action Controller with a single __invoke method.

**Example**

```php
<?php

namespace App\Action;

use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;

final class ContactPhoneSearchAction
{
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response): ResponseInterface {
        $params = (array)$request->getQueryParams();
        $phone = (string)$params['phone'];
    
        // Invoke service method
        // ...

        // Build response
        $response->getBody()->write('Hello, World!');

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Usage

```php
$app->get('/contacts/phone', \App\Action\ContactPhoneSearchAction::class);
```